# Conflict with defining labels in enumerate

Tags: indentation, enumerate

I use to have the issue that new paragraphs within proofs inside an `enumerate` environment would not be indented. To solve that, I added the following in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate{listparindent=\parindent}
```

Now, whenever I have a proof within an `enumerate` environment, new paragraphs of the proof are indented, as desired. However, I have a new issue: I can no longer change the labels for a particular `enumerate` environment. For example, if I have

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(a)]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
```

then it displays as

[image: descrpition]

Now, I can change this if I write

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[(a)] First item
\item[(b)] Second item
\item[(c)] Third item
\end{enumerate}
```

and get the desired output:

[image]

But this can become quite cumbersome to remember which item number I am at and manually force a particular item to have the next desired label. What can I do in order to customize the labeling like you're usually able to do for a particular `enumerate` environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please use either `enumerate` or `enumitem`, not both of them.

Comment: Why should I use only one of the packages? Do they conflict with each other? And no, I have not heard of that feature.

Comment: Well, both define `enumerate` etc. environments, so loading one after the other one will necessarily disable the features of the previous one. If you need the features of `enumerate` and want to use `enumitem`, load `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` and omit the `enumerate` package

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you! Even though I resolved this issue, do you know what may have caused the `label=(a)` to stop working?

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own problem! I just needed to use `label=(\alph*)` in place of `label=(a)`. The counter would work just fine when I used `label=(a)` in the past, so I never had to think abut using `label=(\alph*)` in its place, until now.

Comment: great work! you might also note that you can remove the `enumerate` package

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks. Do you know what may have caused `label=(a)` to stop working?